# 'what are you talking about?' and 'About what are you talking?'

Tags: prepositions, questions

Why is the question '*About* *what* *are* *you* *talking?*' incorrect? and

Is The question "*To* *whom* *are* *you* *talking*" correct?

I know the question '*what* *are* *you* *talking* *about?*' is the correct question.but why can't we move the preposition 'about' before *what*(like '*To* *whom* *are* *you* *talking*')

Answer (score 1):

The following informal mini-conversation occurs regularly in English:

```
I'd like to talk to you.
-- About what?
```

Any grammatical rule that would simply preclude the use of "About what" is a *prescriptive* rule. A *descriptive* rule would say, "The idiomatic way to tell someone, rather impatiently and brusquely, that they are not making themselves clear, is to ask *What are you talking about?*"

*About what are you speaking?* is "incorrect" insofar as it departs from idiomatic usage.  Do you understand how that could be considered a far greater infraction than a violation of some prescriptive rule that has no basis in the spoken tongue?

Answer (score 0):

"About what are you talking?" is grammatically correct and you might see that construction in writing. However, native speakers would not generally say that. Instead, they would say "What are you talking about?".